# Python pip install options

Tags: python, pip

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options

so i have multiple python and i want to install a package to one specific python

for example, python lib is located in /top/python-demo-5/lib/python2.7

i looked at --build, --target, --src and i m assuming i need to use --target to specify installation location

Which command do i need to use?

```
pip install --target /top/python-demo-5/lib/python2.7 <package>
```

or

```
pip install --target /top/python-demo-5/lib/python2.7/site-packages <package>
```

im on RHEL

Comment: Why not use virtual environments (via `virtualenv` + `virtualenvwrapper`)?

Comment: not supported in the company environement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `pip` executable from that installation.

```
/top/python-demo-5/lib/python2.7/Scripts/pip install <package>
```

Comment: it wasnt located under there but i found the pip for the python that i want to install for and did it that way. thanks!